# How can I debug intellij gdsl files?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

How can I debug [intellij gdsl](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) files?

Answer (score 5):

Use println. In order to see the console output, you should first start IDEA from within a script (idea.bat or idea.sh).

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is quite old, it might still help, since the whole gdsl part is extremely powerful but also extremely bad documented.

You can access the Logger via OpenApi from any gdsl file (although usually without code completion unless you include the openapi artifact in your project):

```
import com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger

def ctx = context(scope:closureScope())

contributor(ctx) {
    Logger.getInstance("my-psi").info("I am here")
}
```

The result will be in the intellij system log (Help -> Show Log in Explorer). There you can tail / grep / whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `log4j` with a `FileAppender` (or similar). I've used something like this for setting up `log4j` in the `gdsl` file:

```
class Helper{
    static def LOG = Logger.getLogger( "my.gdsl" )
    static
    {
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel( Level.INFO ) //as needed
        BasicConfigurator.configure new FileAppender( new PatternLayout( "%5p[%d] %c %m%n\n" ), "/tmp/my-gdsl.log" )
    }
}
```

and to emit log info:

```
Helper.LOG.info "wassup?"
```